# Correctly typing a component which is passed as a prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I had thought to wrap the `react-router` Path component. I'm trying to use the `component` prop in the render, but I get the error:

> JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call
> signatures.ts(2604)

The code looks like:

```
export interface Props {
  component: RouteProps['component'];
  path: RouteProps['path'];
  canShow: boolean;
}

const ProtectedRoute: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({
  component: Component,
  canShow,
  ...rest
}) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={
        props => canShow
          ? (<Component {...props} />)
          : null
      }
    />
  );
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProtectedRoute);
```

How can I render this based on the types I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

If you look at the type for `RouteProps['component']`, you'll see that it actually includes `undefined` because the `component` prop is optional.  You get the error about "no construct or call signatures" because you can't construct or call your `Component` variable without making sure that it's not `undefined`.

#### Option 1: Check the Prop

You can make sure that the `Component` is valid before calling it with JSX

```
render={
  props => (canShow && Component)
    ? (<Component {...props} />)
    : null
}
```

#### Option 2: Require a Component

You can also change the types for your `Props` to ensure that `ProtectedRoute` can only be called with a valid `component` prop.  Both of these have the same result, and will remove the error by making sure that `component` cannot be `undefined`.

```
export interface Props {
  component: Required<RouteProps>['component'];
  path: RouteProps['path'];
  canShow: boolean;
}
```

```
export interface Props {
  component: NonNullable<RouteProps['component']>;
  path: RouteProps['path'];
  canShow: boolean;
}
```